# Resize partition for Ubuntu/Windows dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm dual-booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. While installing, I gave Ubuntu 50GB of my disk space but now I'm finding that it is small for me. So is there any way I can decrease my Windows C: drive and increase the Ubuntu partition without affecting dual-boot. I've read posts saying how to do it but I'm afraid that I'll mess up my dual-boot and break my bootloader.

My GParted:

[image: GParted]

I want to take 50GB from from C: Drive(/dev/sda4) and give it to the Ubuntu drive(/dev/sda9). Please guide me through it.

UPDATE : I removed 50GB from my C: drive but I am now unable to add it to my /home directory. I can only make that 50GB into a new partition which is not what I need. Is there any way how I can add that 50GB to /dev/sda9.

[image: New GParted]

The /dev/sda10 [50GB Volume] is the one I want to delete and add to /dev/sda9.

Comment: @karel, I'm dual-booting so I'm afraid that I can break my bootloader. The linked question is not related to dual-boot.

Comment: You've already need to repair your bootloader even if you don't resize the partition. So you should resize the partition before you repair the bootloader. After that to repair the bootloader -- [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: @karel, When I installed Ubuntu, I did not need to repair by bootloader as I could boot into both Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu.

Comment: The link is a good link for your question because it's also a dual boot Windows 8/Ubuntu question. Also please don't ask multiple questions. Instead ask a **separate question** for each topic.

Comment: Ok. I'll try it out.

Comment: @karel, Tried it. See the update please.

Comment: Can you help me? I'll provide the screenshot tomorrow for further details.

Comment: Is there any way I can add the 50GB to my existing partition instead of moving my /home?